# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_EntityAEntityB"

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design

I saw the answers about this topic but not exactly such as mine.

I created a db schema by using EF1 in designer.
I added relation **One Or Zero To Many** between 2 tables (**EntityA** and **EntityB**).
Next I added one record to table EntityA and one record to EntityB which has id to EntityA record.
As I see in design mode (in MS SMS) that field EntityA_id (in table EntityB) is set to ALLOW NULL,
I tried to delete the record in table EntityA.

I expected that the record would be deleted and the field EntityA_id in table EntityB would be automatically set to NULL.
Unfortunately I got exception: **The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_EntityAEntityB"**

Why does the exception throw if the field with foreign key is set to ALLOW NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the exception throw if the field with foreign key is set to ALLOW NULL?

The reason the exception is being thrown is that what you're trying to do affects the **entire row**, not just the nullable column. Setting a column in a child table to allow `null` stipulates that that column is allowed to have no value. Unless explicitly stipulated by the RDBMS, a nullable column has no bearing on a referential integrity constraint like a foreign key; meaning the foreign key rules will still kick in regardless of whatever column specific rules have been setup. And foreign key rules dictate that you cannot delete a parent row  if it has children in a child table. Doing so will render all the child records orphans. We don't want anyone to be an orphan now do we?

What a foreign key guarantees you is that no value will be inserted/removed in a foreign key column, in a child table without referencing a valid value in the key column of the parent table as follows Conversely, no parent row can be removed (unless `ON DELETE` clauses have been specified), if any child rows in a related table.

The [rules of null foreign key columns in MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933117%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)(which I assume you're using) state that a foreign key column is allowed to contain nulls. And that's what you probably have to do to pull this off. Set the column value to `NULL` and then attempt your delete.

Unrelated to this, you might be interested in [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241717)